# How add variables to contextmenu with AngularJs?(Right click)

Tags: angularjs

I would like a some help, I found a code, but it is not complete. 
I want to add variables to edit function for right click menu, but I don't know how to do it.

Example:
How to pass {{user.name}} to edit, link or delete function for rightclick menu?

I was trying, that add a data attribute (data-this-pass), but this idea didn't work.

```
<li class="list-group-item"
          ng-repeat = "user in users"
          ng-right-click="ShowContextMenu()"
          data-this-pass="'{{user.name}}'"
          context="context1">
   <samp class="text-primary">{{user.name | uppercase}}</samp>
   <samp class='badge badge-primary'>{{user.organization| uppercase}} 
   </samp>
</li>
```

Code:
https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/fdkB1W

Thanks!!!!

Comment: use user.name without {{}}

Comment: Thanks your answer, but it is don't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to pass the user in `ShowContextMenu` function:

```
<li class="list-group-item"
      ng-repeat = "user in users"
      ng-right-click="ShowContextMenu(user)"
      context="context1">
    <samp class="text-primary">{{user.name | uppercase}}</samp>
    <samp class='badge badge-primary'>{{user.organization| uppercase}}</samp>
  </li>
```

And in this function you pass the user to a global variable `$scope.user`:

```
$scope.ShowContextMenu = function(user){
    $scope.user = user;
}
```

And finally you use it in your edit, link or delete function:

```
$scope.edit = function() {
 console.log('edit function');
 console.log($scope.user.name);
};
```

[This is your plunker updated !](https://embed.plnkr.co/Kjp7VKGkKMXN9PhrvWFc/)